# Bose 35 Headphones Losing Sound in Skype For Business

Tags: windows-10, audio, bluetooth, skype-for-business

When I'm on Skype for business call and I do something on my PC that **plays** a **sound**, the person talking, no longer plays through my headphones.  Once the sound has played, I start to hear the person again.

How do I prevent this?  Is it an OS issue?  Skype for business issue?  Headphones issue?  A configuration issue or a developer issue?

This was not a problem with [my Sony MDR XB950BT](https://www.sony.com/electronics/headband-headphones/mdr-xb950bt) (at least I don't think it was).  I have the [Bose QuietComfort 35s now.](https://www.bose.com/en_us/products/headphones/over_ear_headphones/quietcomfort-35-wireless-ii.html)

I suspect it plays the Windows sound through the stereo option and then switches back to the hands-free option.  Just a guess though.

[image: stereo part]
[image: handsfree part]

[image: playback devices]
[image: skype for business audio config]

Comment: Are you by chance setting the audio device of the application to the same audio device as Skype?  Be sure you are setting the default playback to something other then your headset.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't follow.  '...setting the audio device of the application...' which application?  I also added my playback and skype for business settings to my question.

Comment: Could it be a side effect of the noise cancellation feature?

Comment: You have two audio devices set to as your default device, which means your audio for a Windows, is played back on both devices

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally figured out a **workaround**.  When I'm on a call, I change the playback device to the `Hands-Free` one and I don't lose sound.  Then after the call switch it back as the sound is garbage this way for music.

[image: select playback device]

Answer (score 0):

For me, the reverse worked. This was because 'QC35 II Stereo' was the default audio output, and Skype’s default audio out was 'QC35 II Hands-Free', so anytime an alert played on Windows 10 it would switch temporarily to 'Stereo' output.

Comment: Please describe your solution in sufficient detail that a person would be able to do what you did without having to look at the other answer and ‘‘reverse’’ it. Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your answer to make it clearer and more complete.